# Overwrite "funcName" in logging

Tags: python, logging

I have a utility method which does some logging.

I would like to see the calling method name in the logs, and not the name of the utility method.

For testing I tried this (later I want to get "bar" from the caller via the inspect module).

```
def helper(...):
    logger.info('foo', extra=dict(funcName='bar'))
```

But this does not work:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1167, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1285, in _log
    record = self.makeRecord(self.name, level, fn, lno, msg, args, exc_info, func, extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1263, in makeRecord
    raise KeyError("Attempt to overwrite %r in LogRecord" % key)
KeyError: "Attempt to overwrite 'funcName' in LogRecord"
```

Here is the output (if I don't try to pass in "extra"):

```
2017-01-30 15:00:24 loghelper.helper
```

I would like to see the caller:

```
2017-01-30 15:00:24 calling_module.calling_method
```

How could this be done?

**Update**

The method-name and other data gets outputted via a logging Formater:

```
logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(name)s.%(funcName)s +%(lineno)s: %(levelname)-8s [%(process)d] %(message)s',
                                   '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an intermediate method which will further call the `logging` method.

```
def autolog(message, extra):
    "Automatically log the current function details."
    import inspect
    import logging
    # Get the previous frame in the stack, otherwise it would
    # be this function!!!
    func = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_code
    # Dump the message + the name of this function to the log.
    funcName = extra.get('funcName') or func.co_name

    logging.debug("%s: %s in %s:%i" % (
        message,
        funcName,
        func.co_filename,
        func.co_firstlineno
    ))
```

Comment: Thank you for investigating how to get the method name via inspect. The question is about getting this name into the logging output (via logging, not via print).

Comment: can you show the snippet of logging func? or are you using inbuilt module?

Comment: the func-name gets outputted via a logging Formater (not in our code). I updated the question. I think it makes no sense any more to show a snippet of the logging func. What do you think?

Comment: Edited the answer, see if you could include a middleware function for calling logger method.

Comment: what is "middleware function" for you in this context?

Comment: This looks great, but I can’t use the `module` and `funcName` placeholders as with the builtin log functions (which, I assume, was also the goal of OP.)

Comment: @GergelyPolonkai updated the answer, you will always have to import the above function to do any logging. The above function can be put in any helper file.